# find file but not in directories named X

Tags: find

Using find (specifically the one on windows that comes with git) to search files. I specifically want to check my entire USB drive but not in folders that start with a dot (specifically .git and .vs) and not in a folder called photos (many many vacation and bday pics, my file isn't in there).

How do I ignore those directories?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d \( -name .git\* -o -name .vs\* -o name photos \) -prune -o -type f -print
```

The `find` command above will refrain from entering the said directories and for all other cases it will display the name of entities found that are regular files.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow command

```
find . \( ! -name .vs ! -name .git ! -name photos \)  -print
```

Where

```
. first is the current directory
```

You may change you location on your demand

Or you may use bellow command also

```
find .  -not -path "./.git/*" -not -path "./.vs/*" -not -path "./photos/*"
```

Comment: I tried on an actual linux distro. `find . \( ! -name ".nuget" \) -print` yields results from my `.nuget` directory however `find . -not -path "*.nuget*"` appears to work. I can't tell if find is searching the nuget directory or not. On windows it appears to do the same thing however using resource manager I see find is searching through the directory every tho it's not matching anything. There's a lot of files so its running slow which is what I'm trying to prevent. Maybe I should write a C# app. I was hoping this would be simple